# How to create a class sub class in a separate file

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

I have a very simple question, I currently have a DB class, who have a child class for every Collections:

```
public class DB: MonoBehaviour {
  // List of items
  public static List<DB.User> Users = new List<DB.User>();
  public static List<DB.Foo> Foos = new List<DB.Foo>();

  public static DB instance;

  // Use this for initialization
  void Awake()
  {
      if (DB.instance == null)
      {
        DB.instance = this;
      }
      else
      {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
      }
  }

  // Defs
  [System.Serializable]
  public class User {
    public string name;
    public User(name) {
      this.name = name;
    }
  }
  [System.Serializable]
  public class Foo {
    public int bar;
    /* ... */ 
  }

  // Method
  public static Add (DB.User user) {
    DB.instance.Users.Add(user);
  }
  public static Add (DB.Foo foo) {
    DB.instance.Foos.Add(foo);
  }
}
```

But Can I move everything about user into a db-user.cs file (And keeping it into DB) ?

Example (not working):

```
// Define the User class
[System.Serializable]
public class static DB.User {
    public string name;
    /* ... */ 
} 
// Add a function to DB: 
public static DB.Add (DB.User user) {
  DB.instance.Users.Add(user);
}
```

Comment: The example you gave that is not working Are you using partial class for  Data  ?

Comment: I'm using it as singleton

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can do this. But you do not denote inheritance with `Class.Subclass`, instead it is `Subclass : Class` so

```
[System.Serializable]
public class User : Data {
    ...

public void Add(User user){
    this.users.Add(user);
    }
}
```

I would refactor the list of users and foos out of the Data class. It would be better to create a DataFactory class that holds all of you Data objects, especially if you're using them as singletons.

EDIT: Looks like you have updated the question. There is no need for user and foo to inherit from this new version of DB you have posted. Change the static lists to hold  and  and you're good to go.